# Define stereotype to use on different project

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-ee-8, stereotype

I have 2 java-ee (helidon-mp) projects (Lets say **A** and **B)**, both share some logic which is encapsulated on a separate project/jar/dependency, the projects are similar yet not identical, to handle those differences I consider it would be a good idea to create a [Stereotype](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/stereotypes.html) which would allow me to specify when do I want to create/provide instances *tuned* for either **A** or **B** project. Given the shared dependency project creates beans it has its own `beans.xml` file, just as both of the projects that depend on it.

**The problem**

I would like to be able to specify the desired *stereotype* to use within the `beans.xml` file of each project, yet when I specify the stereotype at the project level, such configuration is not passed down to the dependency project; this throws an exception with a message similar to the following one:

```
WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type NeededClassForAProject with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject public the.project.class.injecting.dependency.ProjectA(NeededClassForAProject)
  at the.project.class.injecting.dependency.ProjectA.<init>(ProjectA.java:0)
```

When I define the *stereotype* within the dependency `beans.xml` everything works like a charm yet this causes that whenever I need to work with Project **A** I need to update (and rebuild) the dependency project changing its `beans.xml` indicating I want to use the configuration for **A** and same goes whenever I switch to working with project **B**

**The question itself:**

Is it possible to keep my configuration at the project level `beans.xml` and make the dependency project recognize such configuration from the parent project? how

Answer (score 0):

The answer is [here](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/5.0.0.Final/en-US/html_single/#alternatives)

where it clearly states:

> By default, @Alternative beans are disabled. We need to enable an alternative in the beans.xml descriptor of a bean archive to make it available for instantiation and injection. However, this activation only applies to the beans in that archive.

> From CDI 1.1 onwards the alternative can be enabled for the whole application using @Priority annotation.